# Correlation coefficient from sets of x,y coordinates

Tags: cross-correlation

I have 2 sets of x,y coordinates and I am trying to determine their correlation coefficient. One way to do that is to calculate separately the correlation coefficient for the x-values and the y-values. Is it fair to then take the arithmetic mean of these individual correlation coefficient to estimate the correlation coefficient of the x,y pairs?

Answer (score 0):

Taking the arithmetic mean of individual correlation coefficient to estimate the correlation coefficient of the x,y pairs **is Not correct**.

You can use cross-correlation of complex (two-dimensional) signals (arrays).
For cross-correlation of two complex arrays (**a, b**), you need:

1. Take the complex conjugate of **a** after the FFT. (**a1**)
2. Take FFT of **b**. (**b1**)
3. array **c** = vector multiply **a1** and **b1**.
4. **d** = Take InverseFFT of **c**.
5. To find the maximum of the correlation function you can use a maximum of lengths of complex vectors in **d**.

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/736/how-do-i-implement-cross-correlation-to-prove-two-audio-files-are-similar